# Permalinks Question: Adding a prefix ONLY in front of the posts

Tags: permalinks, admin

I want all my posts to have /ARTICLES/%post-name% structure.

But as soon as I modify the custom structure to that, for a reason that beats me, wordpress adds the `articles` prefix across the board.

So I end up with urls like this for my category pages with something like the following

`mysite.com/articles/category/videos`

here the videos is a category and since I did not change the category to anything else, I was expecting the urls to be well, mysite.com/category/videos ), not mysite.com/articles/category/whatever
Obviously, such a URL does not make sense.

On the `permalinks` screen, under the `Common Settings`'s `Post name` option, I get a grayed out ( uneditable ) sample link that shows something like `mysite.com/sample-post`.

I wished I could have edit that grayed out info

to `mysite.com/articles/sample-post` while keeping the other options as is.

But this does not seem to be possible.

Am I at a dead-end here?

Is there a way to only change the post urls without effecting the other urls?

Comment: I *think* I had the same question a while ago: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13411/possible-to-change-the-url-for-the-regular-post-type-without-affecting-the-url-o

Comment: That only takes care of the CPT urls. My problem is on category pages's URL.

Comment: [Custom permalink structure with a prefix just for posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/332921/custom-permalink-structure-with-a-prefix-just-for-posts)

Answer (score 8):

1) Add this rewrite at the end of you `function.php`

```
function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    $new_rules = array(
        'YOUR_PREFIX/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules'); 

function change_blog_links($post_link, $id=0){

    $post = get_post($id);

    if( is_object($post) && $post->post_type == 'post'){
        return home_url('/YOUR_PREFIX/'. $post->post_name.'/');
    }

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_link', 'change_blog_links', 1, 3);
```

2) Go to Settings > Permalinks and click `Save Changes`.

Comment: Thanks Fury, would this ( rewriting flexibility ) allow me to do the following? I got a permalink structure like this mysite.com/cat-base/cat-term and I'd like mysite.com/cat-term to serve that. ( if you do not have a "page" with the same category term, would that work? Would your function can pull that off as well?

Comment: I am afriad not. This code just adds a `/blog/` as prefix before all posts urls. How ever I am sure you can extent it hopefully you can get it work for your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It's working really well for me.

Comment: Works for me in 2021, WP 5.8.1

Comment: This does not take into account paging, ex. `/YOUR_PREFIX/page/4/` will not work

Comment: @ChrisPanayotoff You might want to update this line `return home_url('/YOUR_PREFIX/'.`. to `return home_url('/YOUR_PREFIX/page/'.` ...

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress puts "/category/" by default as the category base in the permalinks even for a category page.

You have to change your custom permalink structure to:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Put "articles" in the category base field and your permalinks for example at category page "Videos" will display in this form:

```
mysite.com/articles/videos
```

It won't work with post's permalinks thought as "articles" parts will be omitted from the permalink like this:

```
mysite.com/videos/postname
```

Answer (score 1):

The [WordPress SEO Plugin by Yoast](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/) has a section called permalinks where you can strip the category base (usually /category/) from the category URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/**
 * Add new rewrite rule
 */
function create_new_url_querystring() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'blog/([^/]*)$',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_tag('%blog%','([^/]*)');
}
add_action('init', 'create_new_url_querystring', 999 );
/**
 * Modify post link
 * This will print /blog/post-name instead of /post-name
 */
function append_query_string( $url, $post, $leavename ) {
    if ( $post->post_type != 'post' )
            return $url;


    if ( false !== strpos( $url, '%postname%' ) ) {
            $slug = '%postname%';
    }
    elseif ( $post->post_name ) {
            $slug = $post->post_name;
    }
    else {
        $slug = sanitize_title( $post->post_title );
    }

    $url = home_url( user_trailingslashit( 'blog/'. $slug ) );
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 3 );
/**
 * Redirect all posts to new url
 * If you get error 'Too many redirects' or 'Redirect loop', then delete everything below
 */
function redirect_old_urls() {
    if ( is_singular('post') ) {
        global $post;
        if ( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog/') === false) {
           wp_redirect( home_url( user_trailingslashit( "blog/$post->post_name" ) ), 301 );
           exit();
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_old_urls' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ended up here, because you have set a custom permalink prefix (for example: `/articles/%postname%/`) for your blog posts (which results in: `yoursite.com/articles/lorem-ipsum-dolor`), but it also gets applied to your **custom post types** too (resulting in: `yoursite.com/articles/customposttype/dolor-sit-amet`), the easiest and most conventional solution is to set the `with_front` argument to `false` on the CPTs.

If you are using ACF, you can find this in:
*Edit Post Type -> Advanced Settings -> URLs -> Front URL Prefix* (set this to `false`)