# how to add prefix to post url structor only

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I need to add "item/" prefix to post url only

I went to Settings -> Permalinks and set this :

```
/item/%postname%/
```

and for category and tag set this:

```
category
tag
```

But other post_type and taxonomies  and author has "item/" prefix

I try correct author URL with this code:

```
add_action('init', 'ztcom_custom_rewrite_basic');
function ztcom_custom_rewrite_basic() {
   global $wp_rewrite;
   $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'author';
   $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base . '/%author%';
   add_rewrite_rule('author/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

But I don't know how to correct other post type and taxonomies

or how to change only post URL structure

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `with_front` to `false` when you register your taxonomy or post type to not have the prefix included in the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is answered here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/63895/51847.
In short you just need to set permalinks to "/%category%/%postname%/" and set a category to your posts (like "item"), and they will display as /item/post/. 
So you don't need to add any init action, etc.