# Permalinks Question: Adding a prefix ONLY in front of all posts with the 'video' post format

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules, post-formats

[This article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52471/permalinks-question-adding-a-prefix-only-in-front-of-the-posts/) is where I grabbed the initial code from, but I am wanting to target all posts that have the video post_format. I am able to change my $post_link to what I want it to be, but when I alter the code to be specific to only video post_format it breaks.

Does anyone have an easy solution to this?

```
function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {

  $new_rules = array(
          'videos/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&post_format=video&name='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
      );

  $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules');


function change_blog_links($post_link, $id=0){

  global $post;
  $post = get_post($id);
  $postformat = get_post_format( $post_id );

if ( is_object($post) && $post->post_type == 'post' && $post->post_format == 'video') {
  return $post_link = home_url('/videos/'. $post->post_name.'/');
}

  return $post_link;
}

add_filter('post_link', 'change_blog_links', 1, 3);
```

Another way I was trying to do it was to change the above if statement to this:

```
if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
  return $post_link = home_url('/videos/'. $post->post_name.'/');
}
```

But that was not working either. I am also not sure how to set my rewrite rules so I don't have duplicate content, the way it's written now isn't fixing it.

I am using the DIVI - Extra theme if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem above is related to the Divi & Extra theme that is being used. That theme has it's own functions and registered the post formats in its own way, adding "et" in front of post format. Bellow this is shown, it solved the specific issue mentioned above:

```
if ( is_object($post) && $post->post_type == 'post' && 'video' == et_get_post_format( $post->ID ))    {
    return $post_link = home_url('/videosnew/'. $post->post_name.'/');
}
```

This is esentially what made the post format function work when using the Divi Theme:

```
et_get_post_format( $post->ID )
```

Instead of the standard WordPress post format function:

```
get_post_format( $post->ID )
```