# Added a prefix in URL permalink structure but the old structure still working!

Tags: permalinks, urls, rewrite-rules

I have added the prefix **/android** in the URL structure of my website: https://myandroidy.com

I managed to do that by adding the rewrite code below at the end of the **function.php** However the old structure (without the prefix) seems also to be working.

- The old URL permalink structure: https://myandroidy.com/ballz/
- The new URL permalink structure: https://myandroidy.com/android/ballz/

My question is, how can I disable the old URL permalink structure? Or at least, how do I tell the search engines what permalink structure should be shown in SERPs by using the canonical tag? I don't know what to write in this tag or where to place it.

```
function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    $new_rules = array(
        'YOUR_PREFIX/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules'); 

function change_blog_links($post_link, $id=0){

    $post = get_post($id);

    if( is_object($post) && $post->post_type == 'post'){
        return home_url('/YOUR_PREFIX/'. $post->post_name.'/');
    }

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_link', 'change_blog_links', 1, 3);
```

Comment: For reference, the above code adds a rewrite rule, it doesn't modify any of the existing rules, though I find it odd that you're adding `/android/` to the front of all URLs and not a subsection, perhaps there's some context that would explain that

Comment: @TomJNowell I am just a newbie in PHP. I just find the above code in another question similar to mine: [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52471/permalinks-question-adding-a-prefix-only-in-front-of-the-posts/) And it worked, however the old structure URL still working and I don't know why. 

Can you please tell me what to change in the previous code to make it "modify the existing rules" like you said. Also, can you clarify what do you mean by subsection, I wanted to have on all posts the prefix `/android/`. It seems that the above code did it successfully.

Comment: You don't need any code, go to Settings > Permalinks, select Custom Structure, and enter `/android/%postname%/`

Comment: @Milo already tried that, however categories got affected as well `/android/category/android-apps/` I don't want that, and maybe all other URLs will be affected too. I only want the posts to have the `/android/` prefix.

Comment: Enter something for Category and Tag base on that same admin page and they will not have that prefix. Custom post types should also be registered with the `with_front` argument set to `false`. The built in `page` post type is not affected by permalink structure settings.

Comment: I set `/android/%postname%/` and Category base to `category` in Custom Structure. And that resulted same as the rewrite code above, The old URL permalink structure still working.

I'm not sure what did you mean by _Custom post types should also be registered with the with_front argument set to false_ Can you please clarify?