# Custom permalink structure with a prefix just for posts

Tags: permalinks

I would like to set a permalink structure with a prefix that will appear just on the posts. The prefix should only be displayed for the posts and not for the permalinks of categories or tags.

I set the permalink structure as `/post/%post_id%` and the post URL is `example.com/post/12345`. But the prefix added also to the categories and tags and it become `example.com/post/category/news` instead of `example.com/category/news`. How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to achieve this result, I used 
`pre_post_link` and `post_rewrite_rules` filter hooks.

You can use eg. `generate_rewrite_rules` hook, but with `post_rewrite_rules`, 
you can easily change permalinks not only to the post but also to its comments, attachments, etc.
Original permalinks you can keep or replace with new ones.

After adding the following code click **Save** in `Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks`.

```
add_filter('pre_post_link', 'se332921_pre_post_link', 20, 3);
add_filter('post_rewrite_rules', 'se332921_post_rewrite_rules');

/**
 * @param string  $permalink The site's permalink structure.
 * @param WP_Post $post      The post in question.
 * @param bool    $leavename Whether to keep the post name.
 */
function se332921_pre_post_link($permalink, $post, $leavename)
{
    if ( $post instanceof WP_Post && $post->post_type == 'post')
        $permalink = '/post-prefix'.$permalink;
    return $permalink;
}

/**
 * @param array $post_rewrite The rewrite rules for posts.
 */
function se332921_post_rewrite_rules($post_rewrite) 
{
    if ( is_array($post_rewrite) ) 
    {
        $rw_prefix = [];
        foreach( $post_rewrite as $k => $v) {
            $rw_prefix[ 'post-prefix/'.$k] = $v;
        }
        //
        // merge to keep original rules
        $post_rewrite = array_merge($rw_prefix, $post_rewrite);
        //
        // or return only prefixed:
        // $post_rewrite = $rw_prefix;
    }
    return $post_rewrite;
}
```