# Permalink Structure problem with cpt and custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm working on a WP website with many CPTs and Custom Taxonomies, but also using the regular "post" post type for the regular blog section of the site.

I want the blog posts and archive and categories to have /blog/ in their permalink, but also want to specify permalink structure for the other CPTs without the /blog/ interfering.

for example:
I have an "events" CPT, which has a custom taxonomy named "ecat".

Now I got an archive page with permalink **sitename.com/events** working well

And the single event page has permalink like **sitename.com/events/event-name** as well.

But the custom taxonomy archive is in **sitename.com/ecat/ategory-name**.
I want the custom taxonomy to have the cpt slug in its permalink like: **sitename.com/events/ecat/category-name**

Note: I don't want the single event to have the taxonomy term in its permalink.

My CPT registration Code:

```
    $labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Events', 'Post Type General Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Event', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Events', 'textdomain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Event', 'textdomain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'textdomain' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'textdomain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'textdomain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'textdomain' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'textdomain' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'textdomain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'textdomain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'textdomain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'textdomain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'textdomain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'textdomain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'textdomain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'textdomain' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'textdomain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'textdomain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'textdomain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Event', 'textdomain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Events custom post type', 'textdomain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
    'show_in_rest'          => false,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'events','with_front' => false ),
);
register_post_type( 'events', $args );
```

My Custom Taxonomy register code:

```
//Event Categories
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Events Categories', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Events Category', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Events Categories', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'textdomain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'textdomain' ),
    'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'textdomain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'textdomain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'textdomain' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'textdomain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'textdomain' ),
    'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'textdomain' ),
    'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'textdomain' ),
    'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'textdomain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => false,
    'show_in_rest'               => false,
);
register_taxonomy( 'ecat', array( 'events' ), $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to WP StackExchange! You may want to try something like this, which uses the same rewrite setting as your register CPT:

```
$args = array(
    'rewrite'      => array('slug' => 'events/ecat', 'with_front' => false)
);
register_taxonomy( 'ecat', array( 'events' ), $args );
```

Sources:

https://cnpagency.com/blog/the-right-way-to-do-wordpress-custom-taxonomy-rewrites/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Arguments

Comment: When I add this line to my taxonomy registration code - the taxonomy archive gives 404 for the sitename.com/events/ecat/category-name (Tried to resave the permalinks settings)

Answer (score 0):

### Prefix for post type **`post`**

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/332921/custom-permalink-structure-with-a-prefix-just-for-posts) you will find how to add prefix only for post type "post".

In the same way, you can add a prefix for the category. Suitable filter hooks are: [`category_rewrite_rules`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/category_rewrite_rules), [`pre_term_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_term_link/).

```
add_filter( 'pre_term_link', 'se342399_pre_term_link', 20, 2 );
add_filter( 'category_rewrite_rules', 'se342399_category_rewrite_rules', 20 );

function se342399_pre_term_link( $termlink, $term ) 
{
    // add prefix only to links for terms of taxonomy "category"
    if ( $term instanceof \WP_Term && $term->taxonomy == 'category' ) {
        $termlink = '/blog' . $termlink;
    }
    return $termlink;
}

function se342399_category_rewrite_rules( $category_rewrite ) 
{
    if ( is_array($category_rewrite) ) 
    {
        $new_rules = [];
        foreach( $category_rewrite as $k => $v) {
            $new_rules[ 'blog/' . $k ] = $v;
        }
        $category_rewrite = $new_rules;
    }
    return $category_rewrite;
}
```

### CPT slug before taxonomy `ecat`

To add slug of custom post type as prefix in term links of `ecat` taxonomy you can use one of the following methods:

- add *rewrite* to `$args` parameter of `register_taxonomy()` (as @Tom suggested)

  ```
  "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'events/ecat', 'with_front' => false, )
  ```
- or follow as in the case of categories, using hooks `ecat_rewrite_rules` ([{$permastructname}_rewrite_rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/$permastruct_rewrite_rules)) and `pre_term_link`