# Get taxonomy link with post type slug prefix

Tags: custom-taxonomy, theme-development, permalinks

I have changed my post type URL structure to have the taxonomy `type` in the URL as well by doing this:

In `register_post_type` (Post type: `release`):

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => __('releases/%type%', 'mytheme'), 'with_front' => false),
```

In `functions.php`

```
function wpa_show_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
  if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'release' ){
      $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'type' );
      if( $terms ){
          return str_replace( '%type%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
      }
  }
  return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_show_permalinks', 1, 2 );
```

When I loop through the available types in my I need to generate the correct permalink for example `/releases/movies/` but when I loop through `get_terms` and display the link like this:

```
get_term_link($releaseType)
```

it returns `/types/movies`. What would be the most elegant way to release the URL with the post type. I wanna avoid writing the urls hardcoded in case it changes.

Comment: Try adding `release` to rewrite argument in `register_taxonomy()`, as Tom suggested [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342399/permalink-structure-problem-with-cpt-and-custom-taxonomy/342646).

Comment: @nmr Thanks, that was so straightforward that I missed it