# How do I add /blog/ on my permalink without affecting the portfolio project types permalink?

Tags: posts, permalinks

I already know that you can add /blog/ on the custom structure under permalink settings. However, when I do that, it also applies to the permalink of my portfolio project types like this:

`domain.com/blog/project-type/%project_type%/`

How do I make the `/blog/` disappear on the project type but not on the post permalinks.

Comment: Did you register the portfolio type yourself, or is it from a plugin?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "post_link" filter with a conditional to check the post type to modify the single posts.

For example:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', function($post_link, $id){
  $post = get_post( $id );
  if( is_object( $post ) && 'post' === $post->post_type ) {
    return home_url( '/blog/' . $post->post_name );
  }
  return $post_link;
}, 10, 2 );
```

You would also need to modify the rewrite rules using the 'generate_rewrite_rules' filter.

Edit: This question has already been answered with a better code example here: [Custom permalink structure with a prefix just for posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/332921/custom-permalink-structure-with-a-prefix-just-for-posts)